# using jquery next to find "nested" sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Perhaps there is a simple solution to this, but I am not able to figure it out.

I have a bunch of images sitting like this:

```
<div class='image-bar'>
    <span>
      <img class='my-image' src='blah1' id='1'>
    </span>
    <span>
      <img class='my-image' src='blah2' id='2'>
    </span>
    <span>
      <img class='my-image' src='blah3' id='3'>
    </span>
</div>
```

Given the id of an image, I need to find the next and previous image to it, using jQuery.

Using 2 as example I tried following to get next image:

```
$('.image-bar').find('.my-image[id="2"]').next();
```

I think until my 'attribute equals' selector I am correct, but since the image with id 3 is not exactly a sibling, the next() is not working. How can I handle this? Any pointers are greatly appreciated!

Comment: having numbers as `id`s is bad practice, also since `id`s should be unique you can reference an image directly with `#idName`

Comment: Can you add complete code, when you want to get prev and next image, on click of some image???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wont' work because the elements are wrapped in spans, you need to go relative to the parents of the images instead.

```
var next = $('.image-bar').find('.my-image[id=2]').parent().next().find('img');
var prev = $('.image-bar').find('.my-image[id=2]').parent().prev().find('img');
```

**EDIT**

Assuming you may have more images to deal with and are interested in the same functionality, you can do the following:

```
var elementId = "2";
var next = $('.image-bar').find('.my-image[id=' + elementId + ']').parent().next().find('img');
var prev = $('.image-bar').find('.my-image[id=' + elementId + ']').parent().prev().find('img');
```

Comment: @UndefinedVariable read into the **parent**, **next** and **prev** functions from the jQuery docs you will see its much easier than appears

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, I would like to suggest/modify your answer to use **find** to actually use a function with variable id

Comment: @AGE Feel free to my friend, I'm simply just answering directly against this question wherein the selector is hardcoded, but there is no reason it can't be more dynamic.

Comment: And also cache the parent el reference

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - it works perfectly. Thank you for your precise and accurate answer that does exactly what I needed. Nothing more, nothing less :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `id` names in sequence I have another solution

```
var imgArray = $(".my-image"); // this will have an array with all images
```

Find image with id = 2

```
var id = 2;
imageArray[id-1]; // returns image with id 2
```

Find next image

```
imageArray[id];
```

Find previous image

```
imageArray[id-2];
```

NB: you need to check if the array index exists.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zz6j0k54/)

```
var imgArray = $(".my-image"); // this will have an array with all images

console.log( getImage(2/* image id */, "next"));

function getImage(id, pos) {
   var returnImage; 

   if(pos === "next") {
       returnImage = imgArray[id] ? imgArray[id] : "";  
   }
   else if(pos === "prev") {
        returnImage = imgArray[id - 2 ] ? imgArray[id - 2] : "";    
   }
   else {
       returnImage = imgArray[id-1] ? imgArray[id-1] : "";      
   }
   return returnImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.filter()` , `.index()` , `.slice()`

```js
var imgs = $(".image-bar img");

var curr = imgs.filter("#2");

var i = curr.index(imgs.selector);

var prev = imgs.slice(i - 1, i);

var next = imgs.slice(i + 1, i + 2);

console.log("curr:"+curr[0].id
           , "curr index:" + i
           , "prev:" + prev[0].id
           , "next:" + next[0].id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class='image-bar'>
    <span>
      <img class='my-image' src='blah1' id='1'>
    </span>
    <span>
      <img class='my-image' src='blah2' id='2'>
    </span>
    <span>
      <img class='my-image' src='blah3' id='3'>
    </span>
</div>
```